# How do you show that the following integrals are equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do you show that the following integrals are equal?

$$ \int_{1/e}^e \sqrt{1-\log^2(x)}~~dx= \int_{1/e}^e \frac{\sqrt{1-\log^2(x)}}{x^2}~~dx = \pi I_1(1)$$

where $I_1(1)$ is a modified Bessel function of the first kind.

I tried showing that the difference between the integrals is $0$ but couldn't find a way to do this.

What other techniques could you use to show the equality?

Comment: substitute u=1/x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x = 1/u$ then $dx = -1/u^2 du$ and so
\begin{align*}
\int_{1/e}^{e}\sqrt{1-\log(x)^{2}} dx 
&= -\int_{e}^{1/e} \frac{\sqrt{1-\log(1/u)^{2}}}{u^{2}}du \\
&= \int_{1/e}^{e}\frac{\sqrt{1-\log(u)^{2}}}{u^{2}} du
\end{align*}